# Generic function for checking max value (String or Int)

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a generic function in Scala, but the syntax isn't working properly. Is there anyone, who can elaborate the reason?

```
def max1[B](a1 : B, b1 : B) : B = {  
  if (a1 < b1) a1 else b1  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code does not compile because `<` is not defined on `a1`. Try reading about typeclasses to learn how you could write generic code over orderings, for instance https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html.

Comment: or one option though not recommended is to use structural types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't compile because the compiler doesn't know that type `B` has a `>` method that can be invoked.

If the compiler can find "evidence" that type `B` has some sort of ordering principle then that evidence can be used to operate on instances of `B`.

```
def maxb[B](x: B, y: B)(implicit ev: Ordering[B]): B = ev.max(x, y)
```